# set_union issue while using arrays

Tags: c++, stl, set-union

I am trying to get union of 4 arrays using set_union. Here is the code I have so far:

```
int setA[5] = {2, 4, 5, 7, 8};
int setB[7] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
int setC[5] = {2, 5, 8, 8, 15};
int setD[6] = {1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 12};

int AunionB[12];
int CunionD[11];
int finalUnion[23];

int *lastAunionB;
int *lastCunionD;

ostream_iterator<int> screen(cout, " ");

lastAunionB = set_union(setA, setA+5, setB, setB+7, AunionB);

cout << "AunionB = ";
copy(AunionB, lastAunionB, screen);
cout << endl;

lastCunionD = set_union(setC, setC+5, setD, setD+6, CunionD);

cout << "CunionD = ";
copy(CunionD, lastCunionD, screen);
cout << endl;

set_union(AunionB, AunionB+12, CunionD, CunionD+11, finalUnion);

cout << "Final Union = ";
copy(finalUnion, finalUnion+23, screen);
cout << endl;
```

When I ran the code, I got the following output:

```
AunionB = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
CunionD = 1 2 4 4 5 6 7 8 8 12 15 
Final Union = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 4 4 5 6 7 8 8 12 15 52187240 1 1863041424 32767 0 0
```

Therefore, the unions of `setA and setB` works as intended as does the union of `setC and setD`. However, when I try to get the union of all for sets, it doesn't work! I'm guessing the last 5 values of `finalUnion` are the address fields but how do I remove them? Also, the union itself is incorrect and I can't understand why.

Comment: how is CunionD behaving as expected? In a true Union, no repeated elements are inserted in the final group.

Comment: @KuramaYoko No repeated elements are inserted if I used `vector` or `set`. However, I'm using arrays

Comment: This is what I meant. How is this an expected behavior in your app. You shouldn't be using an Union operator then. It is misleading.

Comment: I believe that for `set_union` to work properly, the inputs must already match certain pre-conditions - i.e. they must be "sets" with no repeated elements. Your inputs `setC` and `setD` blatantly violate those preconditions, which results in `CunionD` not being correct, and thus being in violation of that precondition in the final union operation, which in turn results in an improper final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the AunionB and Cuniond is not 12 and 11 because:

> Elements from the second range that have an equivalent element in the first range are not copied to the resulting range.

Try this code:

```
int setA[5] = { 2, 4, 5, 7, 8 };
int setB[7] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int setC[5] = { 2, 5, 8, 8, 15 };
int setD[6] = { 1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 12 };

int AunionB[12];
int CunionD[11];
int finalUnion[23];

int *lastAunionB;
int *lastCunionD;

ostream_iterator<int> screen(cout, " ");

lastAunionB = set_union(setA, setA + 5, setB, setB + 7, AunionB);

cout << "AunionB = ";
copy(AunionB, lastAunionB, screen);
cout << endl;

lastCunionD = set_union(setC, setC + 5, setD, setD + 6, CunionD);

cout << "CunionD = ";
copy(CunionD, lastCunionD, screen);
cout << endl;

int *finalUnionEnd;
finalUnionEnd = set_union(AunionB, lastAunionB, CunionD, lastCunionD, finalUnion);

cout << "Final Union = ";
copy(finalUnion, finalUnionEnd, screen);
cout << endl;
```

And then you got the right result:

```
Final Union = 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 8 8 12 15
```

Comment: I'm still getting the result as `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 4 4 5 6 7 8 8 12 15`

Comment: @Ankush after 7 doy you really have  2 ? What compiler do you use ? You have 4 two times, because it is twice in setD. To remove it use std::unique algorithm on the final set or even better on setD and setC where 4 and 8 is twice.

Comment: I added whole modified code. With replaced last lines.

Comment: I'm fine with getting duplicates. The only thing I'm concerned with is that the union is not happening properly and the sorting is also not taking place

Comment: Also, my compiler is gcc 4.2

Comment: I don't know how but I copied your code and pasted it and it works even though mine was the same! I guess i'll check again

Answer (score 1):

A [Union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) operation removes values that the two sets have in common.

Note that AUnionB has 8 elements (not the 12 that your code predicts).

You need to adjust your union-of-union code to account for the actual size of the two initial unions. You have everything prepared to do it correctly:

```
int *lastFinalUnion = set_union(AunionB, lastAunionB, CunionD, lastCunionD, finalUnion);
```

Note that set C has two distinct occurrences of 8 and set D has two distinct occurrences of 4, which is why they appear duplicated in the intermediate result.

**UPDATE**

> Also, I tried your code and i'm getting the answer as 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 4 4 5 6 7 8 8 12 15 . Shouldn't the answer be 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 8 8 12 15

I believe you are correct, but I'm not in front of a C++ compiler to step through and see what's doing on, or to verify your output.  The actual code was edited in by another SO member, but it looks correct to me.

> In the simplest case, set_union performs the "union" operation from set theory: the output range contains a copy of every element that is contained in [first1, last1), [first2, last2), or both. The general case is more complicated, because the input ranges may contain duplicate elements. The generalization is that if a value appears m times in [first1, last1) and n times in [first2, last2) (where m or n may be zero), then it appears max(m,n) times in the output range.

https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_union.html

Comment: I just took 12 as the max size of the union. How come when I printed `AunionB` no addresses were printed but they were printed in the case of the final union? Also, I tried your code and i'm getting the answer as `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 4 4 5 6 7 8 8 12 15` . Shouldn't the answer be `1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 8 8 12 15`

Comment: `I just took 12 as the max size of the union`  The actual input union ends after 8 elements.  The positions 9-12 from the actual end of the union to the position you specified are undefined (if C++ knew where the array ends, as e.g. C# does, it would not need you to specify the end position).  That's also why set_union returns a pointer to the last position of the resulting union.

Comment: Ok. So I changed the array size but I'm still not getting the correct output!

Comment: Visually inspecting the code I think you're right, but I don't have a C++ compiler in front of me at the moment. You might try leaving this question open for a bit to see if anyone can comment on that aspect, or you might try creating a new, simplified question that simply unions (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) with (1 2 4 4 5 6 7 8 8 12 15) and asks why 4 and 8 occur three times rather than the expected two.